# How to get value from datetimepicker

Tags: c#-4.0

I tried to select date and time from a datetimepicker and get value from database, but it's not working. Anyone can help me please.

this is my command:

```
OleDbCommand com1 = new OleDbCommand("select * from tblConsumption where date between #"dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString"# and #"dateTimePicker2.Value.ToShortDateString"#",con);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
 string myCommand = 
   "select * from tblConsumption "+
   "where date between #"+dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString()+"# and "+
   "#"+dateTimePicker2.Value.ToShortDateString()+"#";

 OleDbCommand com1 = new OleDbCommand(myCommand,con);
```

If this doesn't work you can put a breakpoint after the string assignment and see what is wrong with the sql syntax in the debugger.

Make sure your code compiles!

Comment: @RusathFernando - Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please up-vote and accept answer if they are what you were looking for (you up-vote by clicking on the up arrow on the left of the question and accept by selecting the check mark.